# Unzip Password-protected files

Tags: powershell, password-protection, 7zip

I am trying to extract files from a password-protected zip, in a USB drive, using PowerShell. I have looked up many ways but the easiest one doesn't seem to work.

```
$7ZipPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$zipFile = "E:\passwordprotectedtest.zip"
$zipFilePassword = "Foo"

& $7ZipPath e -oE:\ -y -tzip -p "$zipFilePassword" "$zipFile"
```

I keep getting this error:

```
7-Zip 9.20 Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov 2010-11-18

Error
Cannot use absolute pathnames for this command
```

I then moved to the file to my desktop, changed `$zipFile = "passwordprotectedtest.zip"`, changed `-oE:\ to -oC:\`.

That fixed the pathname error but started getting this error instead

```
7-Zip 9.20 Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov 2010-11-18

Error
Cannot find archive
```

Comment: Did you move from E:->C: or from E:->Desktop?  If the latter, you need to provide the full path, 7z.exe won't know where your desktop is located on C:\

Comment: I moved the file from E:\ to C:\...\Desktop (same directory as the script). I also provided the full path to my Desktop but got the first error.

Comment: Try using `Start-Process` and list the arguments with `-ArguementList`  -edit, see [here](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell) for more details

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$7ZipPath = '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"'
$zipFile = '"e:\passwordprotectedtest.zip"'
$zipFilePassword = "Foo"
$command = "& $7ZipPath e -oe:\ -y -tzip -p$zipFilePassword $zipFile"
iex $command
```