# Unzip a password protected file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, 7zip

**Powershell password protected file**
Hi, I'm new to powershell and try to learn some trick with it.
I created a simple code that's supposed to unzip a file using 7zip and a known password.

Here's the code:

```
$7ZipPath = '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"'
$zipFile = '"C:\Users\touff\OneDrive\Bureau\0\Encrypted Zip\test.zip"'
$path = 'C:\Users\touff\OneDrive\Bureau\0\Encrypted Zip\foldertest'


New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $path
Read-Host -Prompt 'step1'

$password = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the password'
Write-Host $password
$command = "& $7ZipPath e -oC:\ -y -tzip -p$password $zipFile"
Invoke-Expression $command
```

**I keep getting these errors :**

- 7-Zip [64] 16.04 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-10-04
- Scanning the drive for archives:
- 1 file, 310 bytes (1 KiB)
- Extracting archive: C:\Users\touff\OneDrive\Bureau\0\Encrypted Zip\test.zip
- Path
  = C:\Users\touff\OneDrive\Bureau\0\Encrypted Zip\test.zip
- Type = zip
- Physical Size = 310
- ERROR: Can not open output file : Accès refusé. :
  C:\ok.txt
- Sub items Errors: 1
- Archives with Errors: 1
- Sub items Errors: 1

Comment: Looks like OK.txt is whats in the zip file but it cant write to C:\
Are you running powershell as a administrator? Also it looks like you got your code from here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189955/unzip-password-protected-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189955/unzip-password-protected-files)

Answer (score 2):

So here is what you are doing in function form to clean it up a bit

```
Function Open-7ZipFile{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Source,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Destination,
        [string]$Password,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$ExePath7Zip,
        [switch]$Silent
    )
    $Command = "& `"$ExePath7Zip`" e -o`"$Destination`" -y" + $(if($Password.Length -gt 0){" -p`"$Password`""}) + " `"$Source`""
    If($Silent){
        Invoke-Expression $Command | out-null
    }else{
        "$Command"
        Invoke-Expression $Command
    }
}
```

And here is how to run it

```
Open-7ZipFile -ExePath7Zip "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -Source "C:\Users\touff\OneDrive\Bureau\0\Encrypted Zip\test.zip" -Destination "C:\Users\touff\OneDrive\Bureau\0\Encrypted Zip\foldertest" -Password "Password"
```

Make sure you have access to the folder you are trying to unzip to

If you do not have rights you will end up with the error you are getting now

**ERROR: Can not open output file : Accès refusé. : C:\ok.txt**

*Edited the function to allow spaces and run silently.*

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `Invoke-Expression`; just run the command with the parameters you need. Here's a short sample script you can use (modify to suit your needs):

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [String]
  $ArchiveFilename,

  [String]
  $DestinationPath,

  [Switch]
  $HasPassword
)

$ARCHIVE_TOOL = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

function ConvertTo-String {
  param(
    [Security.SecureString] $secureString
  )
  try {
    $bstr = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secureString)
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)
  }
  finally {
    if ( $bstr -ne [IntPtr]::Zero ) {
      [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)
    }
  }
}

if ( $HasPassword ) {
  $securePwd = Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Enter archive password"
  if ( $securePwd ) {
    $password = ConvertTo-String $securePwd
  }
}

if ( -not $DestinationPath ) {
  $DestinationPath = (Get-Location).Path
}

& $ARCHIVE_TOOL e "-o$DestinationPath" "-p$password" $ArchiveFilename
```

If the script is named `Expand-ArchiveFile.ps1`, run it like this:

```
Expand-ArchiveFile.ps1 "C:\Users\touff\OneDrive\Bureau\0\Encrypted Zip\test.zip" -HasPassword
```

Note that when specifying filenames, you do not need the embedded quotes. (The quotes are not part of the file's name.)