# Unzip Password Protected File in R using WinZip

Tags: r, winzip

I am trying to use R to unzip password protected files from a drive **without using 7-zip**. My organisation doesn't have access to it, we use WinZip for everything.

I have searched far and wide here but cannot find a post that satisfies the question.

I have a file that is zipped and contains a single XML file. I need to automate the collation of this data, my thinking is unzip then read. I have found these that I can't see what I need to do:

Using `unzip` does not support passwords - [unzip a .zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203800/unzip-a-zip-file#:%7E:text=You%20could%20do%20it%20like%20this%3A%20zipF%3C-file.choose%20%28%29,define%20both%20paths%20in%20R%20the%20classical%20way%3A)

e.g. `unzip(file.xml.zip)` produces
`Warning message: In unzip(zipfile = "file.xml.zip") : zip file is corrupt`

And the file is not corrupt as I can manually unzip it fine afterwards.

Using 7-Zip (I can't access this) - [Unzip a password protected file with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64682048/unzip-a-password-protected-file-with-powershell)

Reading without unzipping (get "error reading from the connection) - [Extract files from password protected zip folder in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460938/r-reading-in-a-zip-data-file-without-unzipping-it)

`read_xml(unz("file.xml", "file.xml.zip"))`
produces
`Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In open.connection(x, "rb") : cannot open zip file 'file.xml'`

I have tried looking at Expand-Archive in PowerShell and trying to call that through R but am not having much luck, please someone help me!

With PowerShell I use
`Expand-Archive -Path 'file'`
which produces:
`Exception calling "ExtractToFile" with "3" argument(s): "The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method."`

Comment: What exactly did you try? Can you create some sort of reproducible example that we can use for testing?

Comment: Does your winzip have an executable that can be called from the command line? if so you ought to be able to do something with `system()` or `shell()` to call it.

Comment: @MrFlick  Have padded out a few examples if it's of any use but none of these inherently require a password so am left a bit lost without having 7-zip

Comment: @Miff I can start Winzip using `start WinZip` in command line but using `system("start WinZip)` results in nothing but a code "127"

Answer (score 1):

I don't have WinZip, but since both it and `unzip.exe` (within Rtools-4.2) support password-encoding, then we should be able to use similar methods. (Or perhaps you can use `unzip` included with Rtools.)

Setup:

```bash
$ echo 'hello world' > file1.txt
$ echo -e 'a,b\n11,22' > file2.csv
$ c:/rtools42/usr/bin/zip.exe -P secretpassword files.zip file1.txt file2.txt
  adding: file1.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: file2.txt (stored 0%)
$ unzip -v files.zip
Archive:  files.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
      12  Stored       12   0% 2023-02-09 10:03 af083b2d  file1.txt
      10  Stored       10   0% 2023-02-09 10:03 1c1d572e  file2.csv
--------          -------  ---                            -------
      22               22   0%                            2 files

$ unzip -c files.zip file1.txt
Archive:  files.zip
[files.zip] file1.txt password:
```

Okay, now we have a password-protected zip file.

In R,

```r
readLines(pipe("unzip -q -P secretpassword -c files.zip file1.txt"))
# [1] "hello world"
read.csv(pipe("unzip -q -P secretpassword -c files.zip file2.csv"))
#    a  b
# 1 11 22
```

WinZip does support a command-line interface, so we should be able to use it within `pipe` (or `system` or similar). It does support passwords, I believe it uses the `-s` argument instead of `-P`. I *don't* know if it supports extracting a file to stdout, so you might need to explore its command-line options for that, and if not then work out storing the document to a temporary directory.

Or, assuming you have Rtools installed, you can use its `unzip` as above without relying on WinZip.

Note:

- Including the password as a command-line argument is relatively unsafe: users on the same host (if a multi-user system) can see the password in clear text by looking at the process list. I'm not certain if there's an easy way around this.

Comment: I have tried this but to no avail, the only differences I see to you is mine has this structure:
`readLines(pipe("unzip -q -P password -c file.000.xml.zip file.000.xml"))`
so I am looking at xml files (I assume that makes no difference?) and in the first file name I am putting .xml.zip

Comment: Have you tried quoting the password? `*` and `!` may be causing problems. (I just tried a zip file with _that_ password and do not experience any problems.) Which unzip are you using? `Sys.which("unzip")`.

Comment: And what do you mean *"to no avail"*? Is there an error? You might be able to use `read_xml(pipe(...))` instead of `readLines` or `read.csv`.

Comment: Apologies to be clear these:
`readLines(pipe("unzip -q -P 'password' -c file.xml.zip file.xml"))` returns `character(0)`

read_xml(pipe("unzip -q -P 'password' -c file.xml.zip file.xml")) returns `Error in read_xml.raw(raw, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  Failed to parse text`

Quotes around password returns the same errors and `Sys.which("unzip")` is `"C:\\rtools42\\usr\\bin\\unzip.exe"`

Comment: (1) Double-check your password. Assuming you have no other messages/warnings, the only way I can reproduce `character(0)` is if the password is wrong. Or if the file is truly empty. (Missing/wrong filenames emit `caution: filename not matched`.) (2) I can reproduce similar xml results using just `xml2::read_xml(pipe(...))`, no need for `read_xml.raw`, perhaps you're using a package other than `xml2`?

Comment: If I follow your example, after creating the files successfully: `c:/rtools42/usr/bin/zip.exe -P secretpassword files.zip file1.txt file2.csv` then gives the error `adding: file1.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: file2.csv (stored 0%)
 zip warning: new zip file left as: zihBdrbc
zip I/O error: Function not implemented
zip error: Could not create output file (was replacing the original zip file)`

Comment: Please make sure your issues are not due to existing zip files clouding `zip`'s steps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep digging, appreciate the help and patience! I have XML and xml2 loaded, might do a full restart and saving of the zip file to see if that irons out any kinks